# Why are string indices legal in JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript

This is legal:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr['ex1'] = 6;
arr.ex2 = 7;
```

Why? Also is it advisable to take advantage of this behavior?

Comment: Also note that `arr[0]` is the same as `arr["0"]` and that you can use integer indexes for objects as well `var obj = {}; obj[0] = 1; `

Comment: Fun fact. the indexer for arrays is the same as an object. arr[0] first casts the 0 to a string or arr["0"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because arrays are just objects and objects can have arbitrary properties. You could do the same with any other object, e.g. a function or a regular expression.

Note that `ex2` is not considered to be an "array index". Only properties with names between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-2 are treated as array elements.

> Also is it advisable to take advantage of this behavior?

<del>No.</del> It depends. I'd argue it makes the code more difficult to understand, the intentions are less clear, and it can be confusing to people less familiar with JS.

But of course this flexibility can also be a very powerful feature. You should use it responsibly and likely only if there is no other option.

However, I haven seen a case where adding additional properties to *arrays* is particularly useful.

Comment: Yep, that's more accurate. `length` can be max `2^32-1`, which leaves `2^32-2` for the highest index. (updated ;) )